# Simplify $ \left(\frac{x-\xi}{\lambda}\right) + \sqrt{\left(\frac{x-\xi}{\lambda}\right)^2+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, probability-distributions

$$ \left(\frac{x-\xi}{\lambda}\right) + \sqrt{\left(\frac{x-\xi}{\lambda}\right)^2+1}$$

Can this expression be simplified further, given the common factor $z=\left(\frac{x-\xi}{\lambda}\right)$?

Comment: No, this can't be simplified anymore. There isn't a common factor exactly, but one could rewrite the expression as, e.g., $$z \left(1 + \sqrt{1 + z^{-2}}\right),$$ or (if $\lambda > 0$) as $$\frac{1}{\lambda}\left[x - \xi + \sqrt{(x - \xi)^2 + \lambda^2}\right] .$$ One could also write the expression as $$\exp \operatorname{arsinh} \frac{x - \xi}{\lambda},$$ but that's probably a less useful form for most applications than the given one.

Comment: thanks, it's a part of an entropy derivation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920468/derivation-of-the-entropy-of-the-johnson-su-distribution

Comment: In that case, the exponential/hyperbolic inverse trigonometric expression might be useful after all.

Comment: I thought closed-form expressions try to simplify out of trigonometric functions